# Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::users does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.6

I'm having a problem with Auth. I'm just learning about Laravel, I'm doing login. I don't know how to fix it it says:

> Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::users does not exist.

this is my code in login function

```
public function getlogin(Request $request){

  $this->validate($request, [
    'email'=> 'required|max:32',
    'password'=> 'required|max:32|min:8',
  ]);
  if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password])) {
    $user = users::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
    return redirect('/messenger')->with('usersignin');
  }
  return "ooopps something wrong";

}
```

and this is where the name from the database will be display

```
<div class="">
          <h1>Welcome
            @if(session('user'))
              {{session('user')}}
            @elseif(session('usersignin'))
              {{ucwords(Auth::users()->fname)}}
            @endif</h1>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `user` instead of `users`, `user` is provided with `Auth` and will get the current logged in user id.

```
$id = \Auth::user()->id;
```

Or you want to get the user

```
$user = \Auth::user();
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by running the below command

```
php artisan jwt:secret
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: it is *php artisan config:clear*

Answer (score 0):

in your if statement just use it as below

```
if (auth()->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password])) {
    $user = users::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
    return redirect('/messenger')->with('usersignin');
  }
```